# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in cassandra connection url

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

Type: Exception report

Message: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root cause:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:69)
    org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:86)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: What version of the cassandra JDBC driver are you using and where did you download it from? What version of cassandra are you running?

Comment: i'm using cassandra -jdbc-2.1.1.jar and cassandra version 3.6 .